# Dataconnection is not there, then instead AD want to draw something

Tags: android, admob

I have Ad in my application. If someone is not connected to internet, I want to draw a text instead of AD. How can I find out once Ad has come to the application? Is there any methods to detect that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AdListener` to detect whether your AdView receives ads or not.

```
AdView adView = new AdView(activity, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxxxx");
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
        // This method is called when ad was received successfully
    }
    @Override public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {
        // This method is called when ad cannot be received
    }
    @Override public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {  }
    @Override public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) { }
    @Override public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) { }
});
```